# Тире или запятая в СПП с придаточным изъяснительным

Tags: пунктуация

Как  объяснить разные знаки в сходных по структуре предложениях? Какой знак соответствует правилам, а какой является авторским и почему? По каким признакам сделан разный выбор?

(1) **Как меня мучил этот недуг — невозможно описать.**

(2) **Что, собственно, с нами творилось, определенно никто сказать не мог**, но мы единодушно решили: что бы там ни было, все дело в переутомлении.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Какой знак соответствует правилам, а какой 
 является авторским и почему?
```

Оба соответствуют правилам. Обычно придаточное отделяется от главного с помощью запятой, а **при интонационном подчеркивании,** как  говорит Розенталь,  придаточные изъяснительные, реже условные и уступительные, стоящие впереди главного предложения, могут отделяться от него не запятой, а тире, например:

*Буде спросит кто о чем – молчи... (Пушкин); Как он добрался сюда – уж этого никак не мог он понять (Гоголь); Что она натура честная – это мне ясно... (Тургенев).*

http://tepka.ru/rozental_2/111.html

У нас как раз такой вариант - интонационное подчёркивание, даже можно вставить "это":

*Как меня мучил этот недуг — (это)невозможно описать.*

Автор сам выбирает, какой знак ставить, но авторским он не называется, авторский - если не соответствует правилам, а здесь всё по правилам.

Comment: Это придаточные изъяснительные. Почему в первом случае потребовалось интонационное подчеркивание, а во втором нет. И что такое интонационное подчеркивание, что мы подчеркиваем?

Comment: Потому что в первом случае придаточное предложение экспрессивное, эмоциональное, почти восклицательное:  "Как меня мучил этот недуг" , да ещё перед "это" -  пауза слишком большая, чтобы обойтись запятой.

Comment: Интонационное подчеркивание - это только  увеличенная пауза или что-то еще? Что с нами творилось -  никто сказать не мог. Или: Что с нами творилось - определенно  никто сказать не мог. Здесь нужно тире, в обоих случаях?

Comment: Чисто интуитивно в первом случае я бы поставила тире, а во втором - запятую, там слово определённо снимает всякую экспрессию, а значит, и интонационное подчёркивание.